# backing up books from iBooks

Tags: apple-books

I have a phone with iBooks installed, and I have read a lot of non-DRM epubs on this device. I wonder if it is possible to back those books up? I couldn't find any relevant menu neither in the software nor in iTunes.

Answer (score 3):

If you sync your phone to your computer, you should be able to see all your files in this location:
`~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books`
Use a terminal to go there, or press CMD+Shift+G in Finder and paste in the path.

Note that your books will not be named as titles but rather the hash of the file. With some basic plist hacking and bash scripting you can rename them so something useful, or just throw them into Calibre and let it do it's thing.

Comment: It sounds great. By computer you mean a Mac? And sync by iTunes?

Comment: Yep! As far as I recall when you sync to your Mac your books should be imported into iBooks. If they are, then the folder I posted should bring you there. If not, there's likely a way to extract the books from the actual device backup.